# why random_uniform with seed return different results

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

Here is the demo code:

```
batch_size = 5
probability_all = tf.random_uniform((batch_size,), minval=0.0, maxval=1.0, dtype=tf.float32,seed=11)
with tf.Session() as sess:           
    print(probability_all.eval())
    print(probability_all.eval())
    print(probability_all.eval())
```

Result is the following:

```
[0.34478462 0.048563   0.2338568  0.5897242  0.01320708]
[0.3184619  0.08369637 0.7260356  0.849159   0.1940335 ]
[0.04257858 0.29290187 0.6533854  0.7465247  0.8997681 ]
```

My question is why the probability_all print different result when run 3 times, thanks.

Comment: When you say "run 3 times" you mean run program 3 times or call `probability_all.eval()` 3 times? It should not return the same result every time you call a function, but the same sequence of results with every restart of your program.

Comment: Thanks, so how should I do to return the same result every time call a function

Answer (score 1):

It's because `tf.random_uniform` will give random values following a uniform distribution. You use a seed to set the starting point for next generations, but it doesn't mean that it will always give the sames results, only that you will always get the same sequence of numbers when running the program again.

```py
tf.random_uniform((batch_size,), #You will get batch_size values for each generation
                   minval=0.0,  #With a minimum of 0
                   maxval=1.0,  #And a maximum of 0
                   dtype=tf.float32, #Using the float type
                   seed=11)     #Using a starting point for the next generations
```

If you want to get the same values again, you'll have to reset the seed between each call :

```py
print(probability_all.eval())
tf.random.set_seed(11)
print(probability_all.eval())
tf.random.set_seed(11)
print(probability_all.eval())
```

Comment: hello, but the following code also has three different result:

batch_size = 5
tf.random.set_random_seed(11)
probability_all = tf.random.uniform((batch_size,), minval=0.0, maxval=1.0, dtype=tf.float32,seed=11)
with tf.Session() as sess:           
 print(probability_all.eval())
 tf.random.set_random_seed(11)
 print(probability_all.eval())
 tf.random.set_random_seed(11)
 print(probability_all.eval())